# How does the following code work in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My controller code

```
public ActionResult Create(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.ALLO_ID = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.AllocationMRepository.Get(), "ALLO_ID", "ALLO_ID", id);
        ViewBag.TERR_ID = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.TerrListRepository.Get().OrderBy(m => m.TERR_ID), "TERR_ID", "TERR_ID");
        ViewBag.ITEM_ID = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.SampleInfo.Get(), "ITEM_ID", "ITEM_ID");
        return View();
    }
```

In my view

```
<div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("ALLO_ID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ALLO_ID)
            </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TERR_ID, "Territory Name")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("TERR_ID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TERR_ID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ITEM_ID, "Item Name")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ITEM_ID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ITEM_ID)
        </div>
```

How these drop drop lists are created? It is not very much clear to me. I want to know how does it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grab the source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and build it on your machine. Seriously. I refer to my copy frequently.

To answer your specific question, i.e. "how is the framework creating dropdown lists?" It's iterating through an enumerable collection and creating a string.

The MVC libraries define numerous extension methods for the `HtmlHelper` class. You can easily define your own. Of course, you can build other helper classes, but `HtmlHelper` is readily available for just this purpose.

Stepping through a few layers of overloads, we find:

```
private IHtmlString BuildDropDownList(string name, string defaultOption, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, 
            object selectedValue, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) {

    var modelState = ModelState[name];
    if (modelState != null) {
        selectedValue = selectedValue ?? ModelState[name].Value;
    }
    selectedValue = ConvertTo(selectedValue, typeof(string));

    if (selectedValue != null) {
        var newSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>(from item in selectList select new SelectListItem(item));
        var comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
        var selectedItem = newSelectList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Selected || comparer.Equals(item.Value ?? item.Text, selectedValue));
        if (selectedItem != default(SelectListItem)) {
            selectedItem.Selected = true;
            selectList = newSelectList;
        }
    }

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("select") {
        InnerHtml = BuildListOptions(selectList, defaultOption)
    };
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name, replaceExisting: true);
    tagBuilder.GenerateId(name);

    // If there are any errors for a named field, we add the css attribute.
    AddErrorClass(tagBuilder, name);

    return tagBuilder.ToHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

It's really not that complicated. The extension methods which use the "For" suffix are a bit more sophisticated.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TERR_ID, "Territory Name")
```

Notice the lambda expression? The framework doesn't actually execute it; instead, it parses it as metadata and uses it to get the fully-qualified name of the item. This can then be used to retrieve various information from the original property, such as `DataAnnotations` pertaining to validation.

The crux of the implementation is in `private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(...)`, contained in `System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions`. The integration with model state and validation is noteworthy.